# How to set COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO using fastlane scan?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, xcconfig, fastlane-scan

From fastlane scan [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/scan/)

> xcconfig  Use an extra XCCONFIG file to build your app

How do you change `COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO`?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
run_tests(
    ...
    xcargs: "COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO"
    ...
)
```